# Rebuild function to work under windows 7 powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function find_sn {
    $line_sn = $args[0]  | Select-String -Pattern "55518" -CaseSensitive
    $line_sn.line.split(' ').Where({$_.Trim() -ne ''})[1]
}
```

Works great under windows 10 but in windows 7 (powershell ver. 5.1) it says:

```
System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Method invocation failed because [System.String[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Where'.
   in System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   in System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
   in Ktr.Agent.Service.Scripts.PowerShellScriptsRunner.ExecutePipeline(Pipeline pipeline)
```

This is a line to split (delete nr 55518 and in output write only "CA015..":

```
55518    CAO1501371925C3
```

Can anyone help me with this?

edit:
This is a powershell installed on win7:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1005
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1005
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Looks like the application that executes your script uses the PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0 runtime.

Comment: There is a edit in main post with PSversion.

Comment: Sure, but the last line in the stack trace says `Ktr.Agent.Service.Scripts.PowerShellScriptsRunner`

Comment: To add to @MathiasR.Jessen's helpful comments: `.Where()` is a so-called collection operator that was introduced in PSv4. Interactively, you can verify its availability with `'a'.Where({$true})`, which should return `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet instead of the `Where()` method:

```
@($line_sn.line.split(' ') |Where-Object {"$_".Trim() -ne ''})[1]
```

Comment: now I have this:
`System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
   w System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
   w System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
   w Ktr.Agent.Service.Scripts.PowerShellScriptsRunner.ExecutePipeline(Pipeline pipeline)`

Comment: I think windows 7 don't like my script runing from SYSTEM user. He need correct paths.